# Firefox adds weird corners on focus on content inside anchor tag

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, focus

https://jsfiddle.net/cvjz1hoe/14/

```
<div>
  <a href="http://google.com">
    <div>
      <h2>Data</h2>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

If I have content in a tag inside the anchor tag , when I focus on it , my outline has weird corner outline extensions. Didn't see this behavior in other browsers

[image]

Comment: Your `<h2>` tag has top and bottom margins.

Answer (score 0):

Instead on having your anchor tag outside your header element I recommend that you place the anchor tag inside the header element. This way you'll avoid that weird corners on Firefox.

```
<h2>
  <a href="http://google.com">Data</a>
</h2>
```